# Getting actual trigger run start time for Tumbling Window trigger

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am interested in getting actual run start time for Tumbling Window trigger. I don't want Schedule Trigger. My scenario demands for Tumbling Window trigger specifically, but also some logic also requires knowing exactly at what time a triggered run started. As per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-system-variables) I tried using `@pipeline().TriggerTime` , basically I passed it as a value to one of the pipeline parameters, but then it was not converted into a value -- then I realized the scope of this expression is within pipeline so I can't use it in a trigger. @trigger().outputs.windowStartTime can be used in a trigger but it doesn't serve my purpose -- I am not looking for a window start time , which is fixed no matter when a trigger is executed. I want actual run start time for Tumbling Window trigger. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: @trigger().startTime is also not useful since it can only be used within Schedule Trigger

Answer (score 0):

One solution I found is that we create Append Variable activity and call @pipeline().TriggerTime in the value section of the activity. Since this is part of the pipeline, it gets converted into a value there.

Another solution is to simply call utcnow() in the append variable activity.